# octobercms How to change the content field widget type on my Blog extension plugin

Tags: plugins, octobercms

I need to have blog post creation that does not use the Markdown widget for content input.

I want to use the RainLab Blog plugin and understand that I should not change the RainLab\Blog\Post\Models\fields.yml since updates will overwrite my changes.

So I have created an extension following the tutorial on User plugin extension at https://vimeo.com/108040919 but of course I'm extending the Blog plugin in my case.

In my plugin extension, I do not need new fields as you see in the tutorial. All I need to do is change the content widget from 'markdown' to 'richeditor'. I've looked through this page http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms, and tried to use filterForms in my new model. I'm not sure however, if that's what I'm supposed to be using.

Anyone had a similar problem with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can hack it like in the code below. This will work as long as the variables are not `protected`.

You need to update the `type` to whatever you want (`richeditor` in this case). You can also add/edit other attributes (`css` for example).

It is important to hook in the *before* event in order to prepare the values before they are used by the Form widget. The documented extend method hooks int the *after* event, so it is too late to change the field attributes.

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function register()
    {
        \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFieldsBefore', function ($widget) {
            if ( ! $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Blog\Models\Post) {
                return;
            }

            array_set($widget->secondaryTabs, 'fields.content.type', 'richeditor');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I haven't had a chance to get back to this.  I had the static event listen method already set up in my custom plugin but didn't know what logic to use and which array to change, since the documentation on this is bad.  I'll try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Rainlab Translate plugin you have to change a line of php code because this line overrides yaml configuration.

Go to controllers/Posts.php and change the function :

```
public function formExtendFieldsBefore($widget)
{
    if (!$model = $widget->model) {
        return;
    }

    if ($model instanceof Post && $model->isClassExtendedWith('RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel')) {
         $widget->secondaryTabs['fields']['content']['type'] = 'RainLab\Blog\FormWidgets\MLBlogMarkdown';

    }
}
```

for this

```
public function formExtendFieldsBefore($widget)
{
    if (!$model = $widget->model) {
        return;
    }

    if ($model instanceof Post && $model->isClassExtendedWith('RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel')) {
        // $widget->secondaryTabs['fields']['content']['type'] = 'RainLab\Blog\FormWidgets\MLBlogMarkdown';
        $widget->secondaryTabs['fields']['content']['type'] = 'richeditor';
    }
}
```

This has a problem, as this plugin works with markdown format internally this is parsed to html format and is stored in content_html column, but with richeditor you already have it in html format, parse will fail and content_html will be empty so you have to print content column in your views